# Creating energy profile diagrams for publication

Tags: software

Is there automated software to create energy profile diagrams like the ones below?

[image]
[image]

One could use something like Illustrator or Inkscape, but they aren't automated, are expensive (Illustrator), are difficult to use, and wouldn't be practical for anything with more than a dozen energy levels. These diagrams don't look like they were hand-drawn, but I could be mistaken.

Ideally, it would be written in Python, but something in LaTeX or TikZ would be workable as well.

More specifically, I think [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/energy-level-diagram/) could be improved upon quite a bit.

Comment: I think I recall from some chat session, that LordStryker was working on something like that, but it was in its early stages and I am not aware that he has published/released it. Other than that I have not yet come across something like that. I know that my coworkers draw them in Illustrator, I prefer inkscape. I guess one could cook up a solution in gnuplot, which is iirc able to produce various output formats. I personally prefer tables though and if really necessary dot-line diagrams. Still +1.

Comment: I've done a very crude one by hand in gnuplot before when attempting to make an MO diagram, but I was hoping for something more "automated" than that (though I would still prefer it to Inkscape, which I want to avoid learning). Anything similar I've just done in Keynote, which leaves me too reliant on a Mac.

Comment: I just found something in my link section that looks promising. Let me know if it helped. Nice Energy Level Diagrams with rxnlvl - http://wp.me/ptBY1-2W

Comment: If this isn't exactly what I was looking for, then I could definitely modify it to suit my own usage. Looks great, thanks!

Comment: Did you come up with something suitable and easy to use?

Comment: No; I did start to hack on that project you linked to, but stopped almost immediately since I haven't needed it for anything. If there's ever any progress on it I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## PyEnergyDiagrams

I use my own script. I have posted it on [GitHub now](https://github.com/giacomomarchioro/PyEnergyDiagrams).
This is the final result:
[image]

It is quite easy to use, on the GitHub readme there is a small tutorial. You have to create an instance of ED class and then add the energy levels to it.

```
from energydiagram import ED
diagram = ED()
diagram.add_level(0,'Separated Reactants')
diagram.add_level(-5.4,'mlC1')
diagram.add_level(-15.6,'mlC2','last',)
diagram.add_level(28.5,'mTS1',color='g')
diagram.add_level(-9.7,'mCARB1')
diagram.add_level(-19.8,'mCARB2','last')
diagram.add_level(20,'mCARBX','last')
```

To add the links between the levels you can have a look to the IDs of the level using this the argument of the function plot `show_IDs=True`:

```
diagram.plot(show_IDs=True)
```

[image]

And then you can use:

```
 diagram.add_link(left_ID_levetobelinked,right_ID_levetobelinked)
```

## Export to pgf,pdf and svg

You can export it just saving the plot from the GUI button or programmatically in different formats for publications using [matplotlib backend](http://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html).
 I prefer to export the plot in `.pgf`   and then I import it in the LaTeX document this allow a full control over fonts and appearance of the figure.

[image]

For reaching better quality you have to change a little bit the autogenerated .pgf file.

The first thing you have to do is to find and replace − with -.

Later you can follow the procedure in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346337/33846) so that the font of the figure matches with the font size and type of the document.

Comment: Wow, that looks cool! Is it possible to export the image to svg or pdf, too?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes, you can it's very easy. But if you use latex I would suggest to use pgf so you can modify your figure later on.

Comment: I have no experience with pgf, and from Wikipedia I get that it is a bitmap file format. While I don't use LaTeX much anymore, I don't see how a bitmap would be superior to a vector image. But maybe this isn't the right place to discuss this. But I will certainly look into your script.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン nope that one is another kind of pgf. I am referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ